# Common Regular Expressions

Tags: .net, regex

Is there a site online that lists common regular expressions or has a utility to help you create one based on sample text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most known regular expression sites are:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

http://www.regexbuddy.com/

http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

Here you have a Regular Expression cheat sheet:

http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/

Comment: that cheat sheet is pay only..

Comment: the version 2 is pay only, not the version 1: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-version-1/

Answer (score 12):

- [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) is a good regular expression tool.
- [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) is a good tutorial
- [Regexlib](http://regexlib.com/) has a lot of common regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Since several people mentioned [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com), which I developed, I'll add that RegexBuddy includes a library of regular expressions for many common purposes.

I don't know of any tool on the market today that can auto-generate regular expressions based on sample text.  Tools like RegexBuddy work the other way around.  You create the regex, and the tool indicates if it matches your sample text or not.  RegexBuddy does provide an Insert Token menu on the Create tab that makes it much easier to create the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

there are some awesome tools for helping create regexs based on sample text, i think one is called regexbuddy (ill look that up when im not on my phone), but the site regexlib.com has alot of regexs for common purposes.

Answer (score 1):

[Regular-Expressions Info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is a site that should give you what you need

Examples page has a nice selection of examples, and the tools page for utilites

Answer (score 1):

Roy Osherove has a nice set of free regex tools. In fact, I think Regulazy might be exactly what you are looking for. His tools page is down but you can find download links @ http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/pages/tools-and-frameworks-by-roy-osherove.aspx. Try searching his blog for more info on Regulazy.

Answer (score 1):

[RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) is an awesome online regular expression checker built in JavaScript. It also contains a quick reference right on the site and a link to a near complete reference from developer.mozilla.org.

Answer (score 1):

The [Regexp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/) module on CPAN lists many common regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows RegX Tool

Try M Squared Technologies - Regx - It is free.
Good for single line, trial and error.

http://mSquaredTechnologies.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm very, very surprised this one hasn't been mentioned:

- http://txt2re.com/

It creates a regular expression from a known string by extracting fields. It's a bit awkward at first, but once you get it, it's very powerful and useful.

And if I'm allowed to post a shameless plug, I have also created my own [commonly used regex table](http://fabiodan.alwaysdata.net/common-regex/index.html).