# regexp for finding everything between <a> and </a> tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a way to make a list of everything between `<a>` and `</a>` tags. So I have a list of links and I want to get the names of the links (not where the links go, but what they're called on the page). Would be really helpful to me.

Currently I have this:

```
$lines = preg_split("/\r?\n|\r/", $content);  // content is the given page
foreach ($lines as $val) {
  if (preg_match("/(<A(.*)>)(<\/A>)/", $val, $alink)) {     
    $newurl = $alink[1];

    // put in array of found links
    $links[$index] = $newurl;
    $index++;
    $is_href = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: 3? 4? times in as many days *sigh*

Comment: Should we close that as it's a very redondant question ?

Comment: Partially this is because the "related questions" feature does not work too well. Partially this is because people are not looking into Google before asking questions (those that do mysteriously stop asking questions of this kind).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard disclaimer applies: Parsing HTML with regular expressions is not ideal. Success depends on the well-formedness of the input on a character-by-character level. If you cannot guarantee this, the regex will fail to do the Right Thing at some point.

Having said that:

```
<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>   // match group one will contain the link text
```

Comment: This will match on any tag starting with "a", up to a /a.  <a\s*(.*)>(.*)</a> will single out a tags

Comment: HTML 4.01 / XHTML 1.0 defines a, abbr, acronym, address, applet and area tags which will all match

Comment: That's right. I added \b to avoid this scenario. @e-satis: non greedy matching is not necessary here, "[^<]*" will stop at the first "<" encountered.

Comment: If regex isn't the best way to find everything between <a> and </a> what is?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I realized that regexp isn't the best way to do it. I'm trying out the PHP html parser suggested by slim.

Comment: @Tomalak : I agree, but I think it's faster for the regex engine to eveluate "not <" that "among an ensemble with anything".

Comment: @e-satis: From a performance point of view, "[^<]*?" is worse than "[^<]*", because the former forces the engine to do a "do I *really* have to match again?"-check every time, whereas the latter produces the equivalent result right away. The non-greedy quantifier is adding complexity at no benefit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of regexes, but this is not the right place to use them.

Use a real HTML parser.

- Your code will be clearer
- It will be more likely to work

I Googled for a PHP HTML parser, and found [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/).

If you know you're working with XHTML, then you could use PHP's standard XML parser.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a\s*(.*)\>(.*)</a>

<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Go to stackoverflow.com</a>
```

$1 = href="www.stackoverflow.com"

$2 = Go to stackoverflow.com

I answered a similar question to strip everything except a tags [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078/strip-all-html-tags-except-links#44124)

Comment: I changed my answer to account for this scenario, thanks for the hint. Nevertheless, your "(.*)" is wrong because of the greedy star.

Comment: This answer is teaching researchers bad things.  Watch this technique fail @ https://3v4l.org/qMd7v == **bad advice**

Answer (score 1):

If I am going to complain about all of the regex solutions, I suppose I need to actually demonstrate how to use a proper HTML parser (the OP makes no indication that the HTML to be parsed is in any way invalid -- so a legitimate parser is absolutely appropriate for script stability and quality).

Now, my advice does require that you become familiar with the basics of DOMDocument (and optionally DOMXPath), but you will see that the syntax is far less cryptic than a regex expression once you understand the components involved.  For this reason, I will also argue that this technique will improve the overall readability of your script (for you and future readers of your code).

Code: ([Demos](https://3v4l.org/qtpkt))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<a href="#">hello</a> <abbr href="#">FYI</abbr> <a title="goodbye">later</a>
<a href=https://example.com>no quoted attributes</a>
<A href="https://example.com"
title="some title"
data-key="{\'key\':\'adf0a8dfq<>*1$4%\'">a link with data attribute</A>
and
this is <a title="hello">not a hyperlink</a> but simply an anchor tag
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$linkText = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//a[@href]") as $node) {
    $linkText[] = $node->nodeValue;
}
var_export($linkText);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'hello',
  1 => 'no quoted attributes',
  2 => 'a link with data attribute',
)
```

if you don't care about the `href` attribute existing:

Code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$aTags = [];
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
    $aTags[] = $a->nodeValue;
}
var_export($aTags);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'hello',
  1 => 'later',
  2 => 'no quoted attributes',
  3 => 'a link with data attribute',
  4 => 'not a hyperlink',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex, the black magic, again :)

I found one [nice question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331426/common-regular-expressions) about common regex. There some interesting links where you will find very common regexpressions like yours.

> Grabbing HTML Tags
>
> < TAG\b[^>]*>(.*?) Analyze this regular expression with RegexBuddy matches the opening and closing pair of a specific HTML tag. Anything between the tags is captured into the first backreference. The question mark in the regex makes the star lazy, to make sure it stops before the first closing tag rather than before the last, like a greedy star would do. This regex will not properly match tags nested inside themselves, like in onetwoone.
>
> <([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?) Analyze this regular expression with RegexBuddy will match the opening and closing pair of any HTML tag. Be sure to turn off case sensitivity. The key in this solution is the use of the backreference \1 in the regex. Anything between the tags is captured into the second backreference. This solution will also not match tags nested in themselves.

Otherwise: Browse this link: [keyword "link"](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=links). There are some interesting approaches to filter links.

I hope this helps :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well.. Using regular expressions is not perfect, but in perl regexp,

```
m!<a .*?>(.*?)</a>!i
```

should give you the name of the first link on that line in match group one, ignoring case.

Limitations:

- Does not handle multiple links on one line
- Does not handle links going over several lines.
- Will also match on anchor tags.

You could work around this by joining all lines into one line and then split it into an array (or multiple lines) using the link start as separator.

Comment: This is not a Perl question.

Comment: No, but it is a question about regexp, and you will find support for "perl compatible regular expressions" in many languages. I would advice to not use regexp for this kind of document parsing today. There are just too many pitfalls.

Comment: I agree; that's why I have whistleblown all regex answers here and posted two dom parsing techniques to demonstrate stable/reliable practices for the benefit of uninformed researchers.

Answer (score 0):

Best and quickest way to create a list of what's between ,  is by using preg_match_all.

Example:

```
$pattern = '#<a[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>#';
$subject = '<a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a>';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

OR

```
$pattern = '#<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>#';
$subject = '<a href="#">2 > 1</a> <a href="#">1 < 2</a>';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

The result will be:

```
Array (
 [0] => Link 1
 [1] => Link 3
 [2] => Link 3
)
```

Comment: This technique is not reliable.  From `$subject = '<a href="#">2 > 1</a> <a href="#">1 < 2</a>';` I expect 2 links, but your technique only provides one.  https://3v4l.org/1atja  == **bad advice**

Comment: Try the following: ```$pattern = '#<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>#';
$subject = '<a href="#">2 > 1</a> <a href="#">1 < 2</a>';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I'm not interested in playing the endless game of break&patch with this question.  Please see how parsing valid html should be executed with the techniques in my recently added answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the pattern

```
'<a.*?>(.*?)</a>'
```

You'll get

```
['sign up', 'log in', 'careers 2.0']
```

Searching in this markup:

```
<span id="hlinks-nav"><a href="/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f343115%2fregexp-for-finding-everything-between-a-and-a-tags">sign up</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href="/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f343115%2fregexp-for-finding-everything-between-a-and-a-tags">log in</a><span class="lsep">|</span><a href="http://careers.stackoverflow.com">careers 2.0</a><span class="lsep">|</span></span>
```

Comment: This advised pattern is missing delimiters and is susceptible to breakage.  Watch it fail here: https://3v4l.org/rJvhR  == **bad advice**

Answer (score 0):

If there would have been some imaginary or invalid edge cases, an expression with a `["']` boundary with `i` and `s` flags would have been an option too, such as in:

```
<a\s.*?['"]\s*>((?:(?!<\/a>).)*)<\/a>
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/<a\s.*?[\'"]\s*>((?:(?!<\/a>).)*)<\/a>/si';
$str = '<a href="https://google.com"
title="some title"
data-key="{\'key\':\'adf0a8dfq<>*1$4%\' >

some context in here <>

some context in there <>

</a>

<A href="https://google.com"
title="some title"
data-key="{\'key\':\'adf0a8dfq<>*1$4%\'>

some context in here

some context in there

</A>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1yjQ5M/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/1yjQ5M/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Using `PREG_SET_ORDER` actually makes extracting the desired values more of a task.  I feel this, too, is bad advice.  https://3v4l.org/rOZCZ  Instead of posting _more_, please focus on posting _better / more thoughtfully_.