# preg_replace_callback just take 5 parameter?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I write preg_replace_callback with 6 parameters like this

```
$aTagPattern = '/<a[^>]*(href=["\']([^"\']*))+[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/';

$content3 = preg_replace_callback($aTagPattern,"next_year",$content,-1,$count,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

And the PHP will complains that :

```
Warning: preg_replace_callback() expects at most 5 parameters, 6 given in /data/www/km/app/webroot/t.php on line 1877
```

But the preg_replace_callback 's decalaration says it takes 6 parameters not 5:

```
function preg_replace_callback ($regex, callable $callback, $subject, $limit = -1, &$count = null, $flags=[]) {}
```

How could this error happen?

Comment: back up the bus... why are you manipulating an html document with a `preg_` call?

Comment: @mickmackusa  thanks! I was using preg_ to make some replacement on some specific <a> tags -_-

Comment: There are DOM parsers for this task.  Do yourself a favor and try it.  Look at how clean the syntax is... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58313334/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

> Version   7.4.0   The flags parameter was added.

Upgrade your php version.

---

Ideally, you shouldn't be using a `preg_` function to modify a valid html document.  You should use a legitimate dom parser.