# where can i get regex for US / Canadian / Western Europe Postal Code, address, phone, fax etc?

Tags: regex

so im looking for a regex or some solution to detect street address, phone, fax etc in western countries.

i know it wont be perfect, but still my priority is on US and Canadian street addresses, province/state, postal code and etc....

it would be nice if someone went out and did this already, instead of me rewriting the regex...

Comment: Well.. Canadian postal codes would be something like `/[a-z][0-9][a-z]\s?[a-z][0-9][a-z]/i`

Comment: @Mark: Many of those are still invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Canadian postal codes can be verified though [Canada Post's website](http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/fpc/personal/findAnAddress?execution=e3s1).

It returns a range of valid addresses given a postal code. I am not sure if there's a web API for it, but it could provide much better accuracy than a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using information I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331426/common-regular-expressions) I searched [http://regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com/) and found  what you are looking for

This matches either postal code or zip

```
^\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5}|[A-Z]\d[A-Z] \d[A-Z]\d$
```

Phone or fax:

```
^\+[0-9]{1,3}\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{7}$
```

Like Ben has mentioned, you won't be able to verify whether or not the address is valid or not, but you can verify that the format is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find some interesting stuff in the sub-packages of [`PEAR::Validate`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.validate.validate.php) *(it's in PHP)* that correspond to the locales you want

For instance, in the `Validate_US` class :

```
function postalCode($postalCode, $strong = false)
{
    return (bool)preg_match('/^[0-9]{5}((-| )[0-9]{4})?$/', $postalCode);
}
```

The same method, in the `Validate_FR` class :

```
function postalCode($postalCode, $strong = false)
{
      return (bool) preg_match('/^(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])[0-9][0-9][0-9]$/', 
                               $postalCode);
}
```

But note that this kind of regex will only allow you to validate that an given code **looks** valid, not that it actually **is** valid : there are so many postal codes *(and even more addresses !)*, the list would be un-manageable, and a maintenance nightmare, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this regex, this will work for all Us and Canadian zip postal codes. eg A1A 1A1 Canadian Zip Codes and eg 99999 or 99999 8989 Us Zip Codes

```
(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$)|(^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$)
```